# how to use signals of operating system to delay a code

Tags: python, linux, operating-system, signals, delay

I am beginner with python and I want to write a code with signal library to show a word on terminal screen every seconds.
I know I can use time library and sleep function to write my code but I don't want to use any other library except signal library
I want to write it in other way without librarys
I was wondering if someone show me how I can do it.

Comment: "I want to write it in other way without librarys" there is nothing "pure" or "minimalistic" about using python "wihtout libraries".  In python world, it's libraries all the way down.   I highly recommend you disabuse yourself of this "don't want to use libraries" notion.  I used to think the same way, but there's no point to it.

Comment: thank you for responding, I truly know that libraries are so important but my question is for a practice which I need to solve and the main task is to write this code only with signal

Comment: Hopefully you're on Unix machine (Linux, MacOS, Ubuntu,...) where signal actually does useful stuff.  If you're on Windows the signal module is pretty much useless and you're SOL.

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You could use an alarm signal:

```
import signal

while True:
    print("waiting...")
    signal.alarm(5)
    signal.sigwait({signal.SIGALRM})
    print("5 seconds later")
```

output:

```
waiting...
5 seconds later
waiting...
5 seconds later
waiting...
5 seconds later
waiting...
5 seconds later
waiting...
5 seconds later
waiting...
5 seconds later
waiting...
5 seconds later
waiting...
5 seconds later
waiting...
5 seconds later
waiting...
```

Comment: thank you for responding, I used it but it doesn't work fairly.  print("5 seconds later") doesn't work and I want to repeat my code, I can not combine it with a while loop...

Comment: I measured the waiting delay and it is accurate within a thousandth of a second (I'm on a unix box though, where signals are a thing, don't know about Windows).  By *'can not combine it with a loop'*, do you mean you are not allowed to or that you think it doesn't work ?

Comment: I mean, it only works once... I've made a while loop but it doesn't work, it prints "alarm clock" but I want to print a string every seconds...